# Spark Target log file already exists

Tags: apache-spark

I am running a spark job. I can see that my job always fails and in the history server I see error

```
java.io.IOException: Target log file already exists (hdfs://nameservice1/user/spark/applicationHistory/application_1456200816465_392022)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.stop(EventLoggingListener.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1394)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1394)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1394)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:54)
```

This is very confusing because it doesn't even enter my code.... I have no idea what is going wrong here. I tried deleting the directory and running again... but same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running into https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4705, which has been fixed for a while now. But it's just a symptom of a larger issue - your application is failing for some reason, and when YARN retries it, you get that error.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error when running Spark in standalone mode (local cluster) using spark-shell.

It occurred due to misconfiguration - I had both `SPARK_LOG_DIR` and `SPARK_WORKER_DIR` pointing to the same folder, with `spark.eventLog.enabled=true` for enabling event logs.

The worker tried to create a folder `/var/log/spark/app-YYYYMMDDHHMMSS-000N` containing a numbered folder per executor. In the same time Spark tried to create the event log for the application in a text file with the same name, so creating the file failed with `IoException: target log file already exists`.

The solution was adding `/work` to the Spark log location for seperating between the worker logs and the event logs.